# How can I use require_relative when compiling with Opal and subsequently running in Node?

Tags: opalrb

I am totally new to Opal.  I am just testing out how to use it by writing simple Ruby code in a local file, compiling it using `opal -c test.rb > test.js`, and then executing the resultant js file using `node test.js`.  This is working fine when all of the code that I want is in test.rb.  If, however, when test.rb has for the first line, `require_relative 'other_file'` and other_file.rb exists in the same directory with test.rb, then it fails when executed with node.  I get an error message that begins like this:

```
/Users/huliax/projects/scratch/opaltest/test.js:5022
  throw exception;
  ^
LoadError: can't find file: "other_file" in:
- /Users/huliax/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@car/gems/opal-0.11.0/opal
- /Users/huliax/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@car/gems/opal-0.11.0/stdlib
- /Users/huliax/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@car/gems/opal-0.11.0/lib
- /Users/huliax/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@car/gems/ast-2.3.0/lib
- /Users/huliax/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@car/gems/ast-2.3.0/lib
- /Users/huliax/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@car/gems/parser-2.3.3.1/lib
```

[This](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/docs/compiler_directives.md) suggests that to me that I should have no problem with require_relative.  I am not getting any compile time errors.  I have also tried compiling other_file.rb to js independently but that hasn't helped.  I can only assume that I am misunderstanding things.  What do I need to do in order to get this to work?

Ultimately, my goal is to try and use Opal to compile an entire ruby library/gem (which consists of quite a few files) to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a relative path with require relative and include the extension, e.g.:

```
require_relative "./other_file.rb"
```

And then when compiling be sure to include the current dir or a common parent dir between the two files in the include paths, e.g.:

```
opal -I. test.rb -c > test.js
```

(tested on opal v0.11.0)

Comment: That sort of helped.  Now when I define `class Bar` in other_file.rb, then `class Foo < Bar` in test.rb, I subsequently get `Bar: uninitialized constant Bar` when I try to run it in opal.

Comment: Is it for opal 0.11? If so please open an issue at https://github/opal/opal/issues/new